# Composition series for Sylow $p$-subgroup of $Gl_3(\mathbb F_p)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Is $ \begin{bmatrix} 1 & * & * \\ 0&1&*\\0&0&1 \end{bmatrix} $ a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $Gl_3  \left(\mathbb F_p\right)$? If so, how would I describe a composition series for this Sylow $p$-subgroup?

Or is
$L = \left\{
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0\\
a & 1 & 0\\
c & b & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
:
a, b, c \in \Bbb F_p
\right\} $ a better example of such a Sylow $p$-subgroup? How would I describe a composition series for this?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since one is just the transpose of the other (not sure why you would switch between two different ways of denoting the elements), they are both Sylow subgroups (just check their order).

Comment: Thank you. I was checking my first example was correct, if not then I'd use the second one, not sure how to write is as a composition series of it though.

Comment: To find a composition series, first find a subgroup of index $p$.

Comment: Sorry I'm still a little confused, thanks for your help so far. To find the subgroup of index $p$, would I use the fact that the order of $GL_3(\mathbb F_p)$ is $(p^3-1)(p^3-p)(p^3-p^2)$?

Comment: No, because you are now only considering the Sylow subgroup itself, so the rest of the group doesn't matter.

Comment: Okay, so I would use the fact first sylow p-subgroup order is $p^3$?

Comment: Not directly. What you should do is make an educated guess as to what "shape" a subgroup of index $p$ (i.e. of order $p^2$) could have.

Comment: So would it be a 2x2 matrix of order p? Sorry for all my questions, trying to make sure I understand!

Comment: Okay, is this correct, let G be the first sylow p-subgroup, of order $p^3$. It contains a normal subgroup of order $p^{3-1} = p^2$, which contains a normal subgroup of order $p^1$ etc. From that we can construct a composition series $ G \triangleright A_1 \triangleright A_2 \triangleright \{1\} $

Comment: See what happens on the subdiagonal when multiplying two matrices.